# Is it possible to access Docker containers living in Azure Container Instance(s) via RESTful endpoints?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-active-directory, azure-container-instances

I am trying to proof out the ability to store my Docker container in Azure Container Instance. I currently have my container in Azure Container Instance but I am trying to access it via RESTful endpoints.

I have currently configured my Azure AD account to grant my application access to the `Windows Azure Service Management API` with the delegate access.

I am also using Postman to create the `Bearer` token to then pass down to my URL:

`POST 
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/slack-bots-v2/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/testing/exec?api-version=2018-04-01`

I am however getting an error of:

`{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
        "message": "The client '<CLIENT_ID>' with object id '<OBJECT_ID>' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/exec/action' over scope '/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/slack-bots-v2/providers/Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/testing'."
    }
}`

**Question(s):**

- is it possible to access my container instance via RESTful API?
- is there a different Azure AD permission that needs to be set in order to access this?
- has anyone solved a similar problem outside of Azure but maybe with another public cloud provider, (AWS, GCP, and etc)?

Comment: It's possible ! It seems like you didn't assign a role for your serviceprincipal via [Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal). I'm not sure the min permission which the sp need, but you can speicify one contirbutor role of the container to your sp.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT thank you - would you happen to know if and how it would be possible to run `Docker run` commands against a Container Instance?